# Merge two parselivelists of different tables together Back4App flutter

Tags: flutter, parse-server, back4app

I'm trying to merge two parselivelists together and show the data accordingly in decending order like I have two tables one for posts and one for reposts that users share. I want to show their data together in a list I have tried to put both the lists in a Column it shows the data of both, but the problem is it displays them separately not merging them together. I have tried using FutureBuilder and ListView.Builder but not able to do it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you can share what you've tried so far, it might be easier for someone to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.